# Codenameone preferences nullpointer

Tags: java, preferences, codenameone

So from what I understand of the Preferences api, I can save a string/int/etc with a unique value as name with preferences.set(String, String).

But why do I get a Hastable nullpointer when I'm simply doing this:

```
private Preferences pref;
private String prefString, hold;
...

pref.set(prefString, hold);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Preferences pref;
private String prefString, hold;
```

You have [declared](http://java.about.com/od/understandingdatatypes/a/declaringvars.htm) `pref`, but you have not [initialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) it. That is why

```
pref.set(prefString, hold);
```

throws a `NullPointerException`, because `null` has no function called `set`. Null has nothing. Null *is* nothing.

Normally, I'd say you need to initialize pref with something like

```
pref = new Preferences();
```

However, according to the [codenameone API for Preferences](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Preferences.html#set%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), all it's functions are static, and should be called in this way:

```
Preferences.set(prefString, hold);
```

Therefore, its declaration line should not be there to begin with.

---

If

```
Preferences.set(prefString, hold);
```

still throws a `NullPointerException`, it is likely because 'prefString' is also `null`.

Comment: same error "at java.util.Hashtable.hash(Hashtable.java:262)
 at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:547)" and at pref.set(prefString, hold);

Comment: Thank you very much, although I was told that I could use Preferences for storing information that would not be lost if I closed the app

Comment: Glad to help, and thank you for the big green checkmark!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Preferences in Codename One is a static API and shouldn't be instantiated.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: I appreciate the non-down-vote correction. I updated my answer. Have not used codenameone before.

Comment: No problem, FYI we fixed the fact that new Preferences() was possible. Its actually an omission in the API where we forgot to declare a private constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that Reference "pref" is initialised with an actual object. Generally null pointer occurs when you try to make a method call on an object that is null. If you ever see null pointer in a line, check the reference that is making call for instance:

```
String a = null
a.equals(someOtherString);
```

you know that a. is calling a method and it throws null pointer which means that a has to be null.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing null to the key or the value where you are storing the data. Preferences doesn't accept null values. To remove a null value you need to explicitly delete it.

Comment: I'm using Preferences to save data entered by the user, but how can I check whether or not they have already entered something? I can't compare my preferences to null or an empty string so I'm kind of lost here

Comment: Preferences get methods accept a default value so give the get calls a sensible default. Just make sure you never call set with a null value.